# iptables not allowing loopback when port is specified

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to configure iptables to allow connections from a remote connection to access mongodb on port 27017. below are my rules

```
  ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere  anywhere    tcp dpt:27017

*reject_all_else here*
```

This works fine for remote connections, but fails to connect on the loopback interface. Adding below with port doesn't work.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
```

But allowing all loopback without specifying ports does. Does loopback change ports or do something else weird ?

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

tcmdump below

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -i lo -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
17:19:49.528039 IP 127.0.0.1.59372 > 127.0.0.1.27017: Flags [S], seq 2525021556, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 10984445 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
20:57:14.735029 IP 127.0.0.1.27017 > 127.0.0.1.59372: Flags [S.], seq 1048378415, ack 2525021557, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 10984445 ecr 10984445,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:19:49.528102 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP host 127.0.0.1 unreachable - admin prohibited, length 68
17:19:50.531012 IP 127.0.0.1.59372 > 127.0.0.1.27017: Flags [S], seq 2525021556, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 10985448 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:09:02.588230 IP 127.0.0.1.27017 > 127.0.0.1.59372: Flags [S.], seq 1064049928, ack 2525021557, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 10985448 ecr 10985448,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:19:50.531066 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP host 127.0.0.1 unreachable - admin prohibited, length 68
17:19:52.535030 IP 127.0.0.1.59372 > 127.0.0.1.27017: Flags [S], seq 2525021556, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 10987452 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
00:32:29.704695 IP 127.0.0.1.27017 > 127.0.0.1.59372: Flags [S.], seq 1095362915, ack 2525021557, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 10987452 ecr 10987452,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:19:52.535109 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP host 127.0.0.1 unreachable - admin prohibited, length 68
```

Comment: Please add the output of `tcpdump -i lo -n` while accessing the service.

Comment: added the tcpdump. seems like some port 59372 is being used. Is that the source port ?

Comment: Yes, that is the source port.

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to what it seems like the problem is not connecting to the service: The problem is the response.

I guess that your Netfilter configuration is missing this important standard rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: my output connections are not filtered, so makes sense that a remote mongo would get the response, and why local mongo is failing since it goes through the INPUT filter and fails. your solution doesnt work , but puts me in the right direction. thanks.

Comment: @AbhinavVishak I assume the remote mongo works because there is a similar rule limited to the external interface. Without such a rule you could not even access web sites.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Hauke's answer the following worked for me .

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

mongo was able to reach mongod through the INPUT rule, but as Hauke pointed out, the response from mongod was getting filtered( as opposed to a remote connection since all outbound traffic is allowed).